# Subresouce Integrity CORS breaking on Chrome

Tags: amazon-s3, cross-domain, amazon-cloudfront, subresource-integrity

I have a js file in an s3 bucket, served by cloudfront, which is called through a cname.

request -> cname.fake.com -> cloudfront -> s3bucket

The tag generated has an integrity and cossorigin attribute and seems to work in all browsers but chrome which gives me a CORS error. If I have the tag src point directly to cloudfront the asset is served correctly. I used mitproxy to monitor the request and when making it to the cname, chrome cancels the request before it is even made. Allow access control headers are passed, any ideas?